# mod_rewrite redirect or block heavy traffic what's not mentioned for me

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, post, get

The following is generating a lot of traffic but it's not for me.
Or they try to break in or they are voting for a house number, not sure.

Log:

POST /?xclzve_ty4AGLRXcipv06CINTZekrx28EKPVb HTTP/1.1

GET /?xclzve_lsx27CHMRWbglrw16BHMRWciou05AF HTTP/1.1

Is it possible to redirect to a 404 page or block ?xclzve_* (?xclzve_ is the same but the number or line behind it is different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root (or your vhost config)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} xclzve_
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

This will return a 403 Forbidden, or you can replace `F`, with `R=404` for a 404 not found.

Though you may want to block the IP address(es) that these requests are coming from? If it's just one or two, you can do:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny From 123.45.67.89
```

if 123.45.67.89 is one of the IP's sending bogus requests. It may be a tad faster than using the rewrite engine.

Comment: Your solution worked, perfect :-). Well blocking the IP's is not really an option. To many. I searched for "xclzve_" and I guess people are voting for a song. Using a script for it and using my domain name. Not knowing that I have nothing to do with it. The 404 not found will make this clear for them. (I hope)

Comment: @Gfive I doubt this is going to deter whatever is going on, but at least it's not using the resources to run whatever index script you have. Also, you should accept the answer so that this question shows up as resolved.

Comment: thanks Lin, yes resources are almost none now. (before it was loading my website. Now just the standard apache message.